# Best approximation of an irrational number by primes $2,3,5,7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, approximation

Let $G$ be the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{R}_+,\cdot)$, which is the positive real numbers equipped with the usual distance. Let $P$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $2,3,5,7$, i.e.
$$P = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty\{2,3,5,7,\frac12,\frac13,\frac15\frac17\}^n$$
I have a few questions.

1. Is the subgroup $P$ dense in $(\mathbb{R}_+,\cdot)$?
2. What is the best approximation of $\sqrt2$ or $\pi$ in $P$ given the constraint that, for example, the total number of primes used is less than $1000$? I'm allowed only to use $2,3,5,7$ and no more.

I know that a nontrivial additive subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$ is either dense or discrete, so we can transform $2,3,5,7$ into $\log 2,\log3,\log5,\log7$ and consider the subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$ generated by $\log 2,\log3,\log5,\log7$, which I believe is dense. Then we can approximate $\log \sqrt2=\frac12\log2$ by an integer combination of these elements.

However, I've done some simulations and the best approximation I can find is $\frac{7^3}{3^5}\approx 1.411522633744856$, which makes me suspect it is not dense. Where did I go wrong? Does there exist an algorithm for finding such combinations?

> Edit: I just found out that $\sqrt2$ is a very special case because $\log\sqrt2=\frac12\log2$. What if I want to approximate $\pi$? I used @lulu's method and got
> $$3^a=2^b\pi\implies a\log3=b\log2+\log\pi\implies \frac{a}{b+\frac{\log\pi}{\log2}}=\frac{\log2}{\log3}$$

Or I want to use all of $2,3,5,7$.$$2^a3^b5^c7^d=\sqrt2$$
$$a\log2+b\log3+c\log5+d\log7=\frac12\log2$$
$$2b\log3+2c\log5+2d\log7=(1-2a)\log2$$
$$\frac{2b+2\frac{\log5}{\log3}c+2\frac{\log7}{\log3}d}{1-2a}=\frac{\log2}{\log3}$$
but I couldn't proceed.

Comment: Using continued fractions, I get $\frac {3^{55601}}{2^{88125}}=1.4142\cdots$...and that's just sticking to $2,3$.  N.B.  Looking at those values, I wouldn't expect much from trial and error.

Comment: The method:  say $3^a=2^b\times \sqrt 2$.  Then we get $\frac {2a}{2b+1}=\frac {\log 2}{\log 3}$.  We then look at [convergents](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=convergents%5Blog%5B2%5D%2Flog%5B3%5D%2C20%5D) to the right hand.  We want the numerator to be even and the denominator to be odd, lots of options.  I got my values from the convergent $\frac {111202}{176251}$. We'd do even better if we took the last one in that short table.

Comment: For practical purposes , there are better approaches to approximate irrational numbers. Why are you interested to use this special and very small set ?

Comment: OK, I'm confused. By multiplicative closure on `P` (since it's a subgroup and thus a group), it appears you can get any rational number by multiplying primes for the numerator and 1/primes for the denominator and then multiply the two. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is not a practical problem. I'm allowed only to use 2,3,5,7 and no more. Is there any method to use all of them instead of just 2 and 3?

Comment: @lulu Thanks a lot! Is there any way to use all of them, which I think will make convergence faster.

Comment: But...why?  The convergents are so easy to obtain and they are "optimal" in a fairly well defined sense.  In any case, I would imagine the method could be adapted.

Comment: For example, if we add the constraint that the total number of primes used is less than 1000, then using all of 2,3,5,7 will get a better approximation than just using 2,3. I'm having trouble adapting your method to using all of 2,3,5,7. Could you write an answer?

Comment: where did you get the problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with LLL type algorithms?

Comment: I think you get to an integer programming issue.  Something of the form $\sum a_i\log p_i= \log X$ where the $a_i$ are integers,  possibly negative.  You can more constraints to that as you like,  but integer programming problems tend to be a bit difficult to optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1:** Yes, this subgroup is dense, and in fact any two distinct primes would suffice. Here are two general claims.

> **Claim 1:** The subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is dense as soon as there exist two elements $x, y \in S$ such that $\frac{y}{x}$ is irrational.

> **Claim 2:** If $p, q$ are distinct primes then $\frac{\log p}{\log q}$ is irrational.

Claim 1 follows from [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) and Claim 2 has a very short proof as follows: if $\frac{\log p}{\log q} = \frac{a}{b}$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ then we would have $p = q^{\frac{a}{b}}$ and hence $p^b = q^a$ but this contradicts unique prime factorization. (It is harder but still true that $\frac{\log p}{\log q}$ is transcendental; this follows from the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).)

I don't have any insight into Q2 beyond what lulu says in the comments about continued fractions but maybe [integer relation algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm) could be helpful.